# Is this ratio of difference of these functions monotonic?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, monotone-functions

1. If $f(x)$ is monotonic decreasing and $g(x)$ is monotonic increasing then is $([f(x)]^n - [g(x)]^n)/(f(x)-g(x))$ monotonicslly decreasing always or under any specific conditions? All functions above are real valued. I was thinking one condition would be if $g(x) < f(x)$. My intuition was also intending to show rate of decrease of numerator is greater than rate of decrease of denominator. Posting here to get a comprehensive and thorough answer...
2. If we instead had denominator to be just $f(x)$, what would be the answer then?

Comment: I can write in this form and do derivative sign test for monotonicity. That said, what is this equality called if any or if there is a reference to it?

Comment: Also looks like analysis needs to be done for k above and below n/2 separately and combined?

Comment: "That said, what is this equality called"  Which equality?

Comment: Slight error:  Should read $\frac{f^{n+1}-g^{n+1}}{f-g}=\sum_{k=0}^nf^kg^{n-k}$.  I deleted the other one.  It is a generalization of the sum of a finite geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

(I will assume that the denominators don't vanish). There are many examples where $\frac {f^{n}-g^{n}} {f-g}$ is not monotonic. If $f$ and $g$ are non-negative and monotonically increasing then $\frac {f^{n}-g^{n}} {f-g}$ is monotonically increasing using the comment by Herb Steinberg. If $f$ is decreasing and $g$ is increasing there is no reason for $\frac {f^{n}-g^{n}} {f-g}$ to be monotonic, even with $n=2$. Without non-negativity a simple counterexample with both $f$ and $g$ increasing is $f(x)=-1, g(x)=x$ with $n=3$. In this case $\frac {f^{n}-g^{n}} {f-g}$ is increasing for $x >-\frac 1 2$ and decreasing for $x <-\frac 1 2$. As for part 2), we can rarely say that the ratio $\frac {f^{n}-g^{n}} f$ is monotonic. Even with $n=1$ monotonicity may not hold.

Comment: by Herb Steinberg's comment would it be increasing or decreasing? doesn't it depend on rate of decrease of f vs rate of increase of g ?

Comment: @pMan Corrected the mistakes.

Comment: if say I bring up this example case: $f(x) = e^{-(x.c)^k}$ and $g(x) = x^2$ and if $c >> x$, $k$ is a large number then since $f^n$ decreases faster than rate of increase of $g^n$ , therefore numerator $f^n - g^n$ decreases faster than rate of increase of $1/(f-g)$, can this be example be generalized to come up with a condition instead based on rates of increases/decreases of $f, g$ for the ratio to be monotonic decreasing?

Comment: I guess issue is when f limits to 0 in this example

Comment: @pMan I would suggest that you work with a few examples to see what to expect for the ratios.